# Where can I find the zoo on Mother Base?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain, what platform can I find the zoo of where I have all of my Fultoned animals?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. While this may sound like a silly question, it's actually pretty well hidden.

Comment: @twobugs It is what people call "drive-by downvoting". They can get cheap and abusive rep that way.

Comment: It's not *that* well hidden, it just takes a while to become unlocked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you are in the helicopter and selecting which platform you want to land on, Press the Action button (triangle on PS4) to switch to the Animal Conservation platform. It is a separate platform from the standard Mother Base layout, not attached, but in a different 'location'.

Comment: Does getting to the zoo require any upgrades to the Mother Base or is it available from the first time I get to the MB?

Comment: The platform is constructed automatically at no expense to you after extracting your first few beasties